trouble with DNS ports config
I'm just starting out setting up my own server (VPS) so still on the steep learning curve.
I'm running it on Ubuntu 22.04 with Cloudpanel installed to manage the sites. Cloudpanel loads successfully when accessing the server using the IP but when I assiged the sever a URL (subdomain to open the panel), I found that it only works if I add :8445 to the URL (it looks like this: (https://yotamguttman.eu:8443).
my understanding of DNS configs is still limited but from my research I found that it's possible that there's either a port conflict or the HTTPS 443 port is blocked by the server firewall and the way to resolve it is to configure it differently in the server.
if anyone has an idea about it, I'd appreciate an advice!
thanks :)

DNS, the Domain Name System, has nothing to do with ports (:443). Otherwise, use traceroute (read man traceroute), install the TCP Traceroute (sudo apt install tracepath;man tracepath). Warning: It may be a violation of your ISP's Terms of Service to work around ISP restrictions,  and consequences may be harsh.
